# Dado aparecendo duplicado

Tags: java, classes

Queria saber por que quando eu executo esse código ele mostra duas vezes o nome do cliente e funcionário, e como resolver pra aparecer só uma vez

```
package modelo;

import java.util.Date;

public class Pessoa {

    public int codigo;
    public String nome;
    public Date dataNascimento;
    public String endereco;

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }
    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public Date getDataNascimento() {
        return dataNascimento;
    }
    public void setDataNascimento(Date dataNascimento) {
        this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    }
    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }
    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }



}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------package modelo;


public class Funcionario extends Pessoa {

}
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
package modelo;

public class Cliente extends Pessoa {

}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
package modelo;

public class Produto {
    public int codigo;
    public String nome;
    public double preco;
    public int quantidadeEstoque;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public double getPreco() {
        return preco;
    }
    public void setPreco(double preco) {
        this.preco = preco;
    }
    public int getQuantidadeEstoque() {
        return quantidadeEstoque;
    }
    public void setQuantidadeEstoque(int quantidadeEstoque) {
        this.quantidadeEstoque = quantidadeEstoque;
    }
    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }
    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }


}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------package movimento;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import modelo.Produto;

public class ItensVenda {


    public ArrayList<Produto> listaDeProduto = new ArrayList<Produto>();
    public double valorTotal = 0;


    public ArrayList<Produto> getListaDeProduto() {
        return listaDeProduto;
    }
    public void setListaDeProduto(ArrayList<Produto> listaDeProduto) {
        this.listaDeProduto = listaDeProduto;
    }
    public double getValorTotal() {
        return valorTotal;
    }
    public void setValorTotal(double valorTotal) {
        this.valorTotal = valorTotal;
    }


}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
package movimento;

import modelo.Cliente;
import modelo.Funcionario;

public class Venda {
    private ItensVenda itensVenda;
    private Funcionario funcionario;
    private Cliente cliente;

    public ItensVenda getItensVenda() {
        return itensVenda;
    }

    public void setItensVenda(ItensVenda itensVenda) {
        this.itensVenda = itensVenda;
    }

    public Funcionario getFuncionario() {
        return funcionario;
    }

    public void setFuncionario(Funcionario funcionario) {
        this.funcionario = funcionario;
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }


}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
package main;

import java.util.Date;

import modelo.Cliente;
import modelo.Funcionario;
import modelo.Produto;
import movimento.ItensVenda;
import movimento.Venda;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Produto banana = new Produto();
        banana.setCodigo(1);
        banana.setNome("Banana");
        banana.setPreco(8.00);
        banana.setQuantidadeEstoque(100);

        Produto maca = new Produto();
        maca.setCodigo(2);
        maca.setNome("Maca");
        maca.setPreco(8.00);
        maca.setQuantidadeEstoque(100);

        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        cliente.setCodigo(1);
        cliente.setDataNascimento(new Date());
        cliente.setEndereco("Rua rocha pombo");
        cliente.setNome("Valdecir");

        Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario();
        funcionario.setCodigo(1);
        funcionario.setDataNascimento(new Date());
        funcionario.setEndereco("Vila Operaria");
        funcionario.setNome("Ricardo");

        ItensVenda itensVenda = new ItensVenda();
        itensVenda.listaDeProduto.add(banana);
        itensVenda.listaDeProduto.add(maca);

        Venda venda = new Venda();
        venda.setItensVenda(itensVenda);
        venda.setCliente(cliente);
        venda.setFuncionario(funcionario);

        for (int i = 0; i < venda.getItensVenda().getListaDeProduto().size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Nome do Cliente: " + venda.getCliente().getNome());
            System.out.println("Nome do Funcionario: " + venda.getFuncionario().getNome());
            System.out.println("Nome do Produto: " + venda.getItensVenda().getListaDeProduto().get(i).nome);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Poste as outras classes para podermos testar.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi o problema todo está na modelagem. Está cadastrando o cliente e o funcionário como informação relevante para o item de venda, quando na verdade deveria ser só informação da venda como um todo e não cada item. Como você tem 2 itens, o dado aparece duas vezes, um para cada item. Então remodela sua venda para ter esses dados lá e retire eles do item de venda.

A resposta do AP resolve o sintoma, mas não o problema. Agora tem algo assim:

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Fazendo assim resolve o problema pontual, mas o modelo continuar errado se sempre precisará de gambiarras para resolver. É melhor dar a solução correta.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, é so fazer assim:

```
System.out.println("Nome do Cliente: " + venda.getCliente().getNome());
    System.out.println("Nome do Funcionario: " + venda.getFuncionario().getNome());
    for (int i = 0; i < venda.listaDeItensVenda.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println(
                "Nome do Produto: " + venda.getListaDeItensVenda().get(i).getListaDeProduto().get(i).getNome());

    }
```

eu estava printando o nome do cliente e funcionario dentro do for e o correto é fora

Comment: Resolveu o sintoma não o problema.